# What learning to read software is available?

Tags: software-recommendation

What packages are available for Ubuntu to help a 7 year old child learn to read?

I've seen Gcompris, but not sure that will be developed enough.

What other packages would be compatible for Ubuntu (10.10, or 11.4)?

Answer (score 0):

I know Gcompris has activities for lecture practice.

You might want to check [Doudoulinux](http://doudoulinux.org/) and/or [Qimo](http://www.qimo4kids.com/) -- both linux distros developed for children-- or, at least, find the list of their applications. You might find something you can use.

Regards.

Comment: It's sorely tempting to install these on our directors PC's ;)